# lightbox zoom for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, lightbox2

I need to install zoom option for light box, similar to what found in this page

http://www.bustler.net/index.php/article/seoul_memorial_park_by_haeahn_architecture/
(Click on the image to enlarge- zoom option is on the top left side)

I don't know the name of this ZOOM plugin, anyone could help me please?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called "Fancybox For Wordpress" or "Auto Thinkbox" that has similar effects.